# What does it mean that Kubernetes removed support for Docker but supports containerd (which is part of Docker)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

What does it mean that Kubernetes removed support for Docker but supports containerd. Docker developed containerd and uses it for managing containers.

Are there 2 different containerd?

1. one that is supported by kubernetes
2. another one which is used by docker

If not, then why kubernetes cannot talk/use to containerd used by the Docker daemon?

Comment: Please read the article @danielorn references. Unless you are a Kubernetes developer of any kind (or monitoring software developer), it does not negatively affect you, since Kubernetes still runs Docker-created images.

Answer (score 7):

### In short

- [containerd](https://containerd.io/) is part of Docker (the part that pulls and runs images)
- Since Kubernetes is concerned only with pulling and running images and not creating them, it makes little sense to support Docker (which does not implement [CRI](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/12/container-runtime-interface-cri-in-kubernetes/)) as a runtime, when containerd (which implements CRI) is the only thing that is needed
- Even though Kubernetes drops support for Docker as a container runtime, images created with docker will still work in Kubernetes since they follow the [OCI-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/runtime-spec/blob/master/spec.md).

> Docker as an underlying runtime is being deprecated in favor of
> runtimes that use the Container Runtime Interface (CRI) created for
> Kubernetes. Docker-produced images will continue to work in your
> cluster with all runtimes, as they always have.

### The longer answer

**containerd is a container runtime, which is a piece of software that pulls images, manages networking, storage and starts containers** (using [runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc)). There are other container runtimes, such as [cri-o](https://cri-o.io/) that can be used for this purpose also. Those container runtime can handle any image following the OCI-spec, which is a specification of the container image format.

**Docker on the other hand is much more than that**. It is a multi-competent tool that can both create OCI compliant images as well as running them. When Docker pulls or runs an image it uses containerd.

Kubernetes relies heavily on a plugin architecture where various needs like storage, networking etc can be fullfilled by any implementation that adheres to the interface Kubernetes specifies. For container runtimes, **Kubernetes defines the Container Runtime Interface CRI, and any container runtime that implements that interface can be used to pull images and launch containers in Kubernetes**.

The extra features, like creating images etc that comes with Docker has little to no value for Kubernetes, which is concerned with pulling images and running containers only. **The fact that Docker does not implement CRI makes it unneccessary complex for Kubernetes to support Docker as a runtime**, when all it needs is the containerd runtime.

> [...]
>
> Docker is cool and useful because it has a lot of UX enhancements
> that make it really easy for humans
>
> [...]
>
> As a result of this human-friendly abstraction layer, your Kubernetes
> cluster has to use another tool called Dockershim to get at what it
> really needs, which is containerd. That’s not great, because it gives
> us another thing that has to be maintained and can possibly break.
> What’s actually happening here is that Dockershim is being removed
> from Kubelet as early as v1.23 release, which removes support for
> Docker as a container runtime as a result. You might be thinking to
> yourself, but if containerd is included in the Docker stack, why does
> Kubernetes need the Dockershim?
>
> Docker isn’t compliant with CRI, the Container Runtime Interface. If
> it were, we wouldn’t need the shim, and this wouldn’t be a thing

Quotes are taken from the article [Don't Panic: Kubernetes and Docker](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/)

Comment: thanks for the insights. can kubernetes 1.22 still work with contianerd that comes bundled with dockerd?

Comment: containerd is containerd, regardless of if it comes bundled with docker or not. containerd has been a supported container runtime since Kubernetes 1.10 and will continue to be so. However support for Docker as a runtime is planned to be removed in version 1.22. After that it is no longer possible to configure Kubernetes to use Docker as a runtime, instead you will need to use containerd (or another CNI compliant runtime). For details on how to configure containerd, please see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd